# What causes the difference appearance by the useages of two "csname...endcsname"?

Tags: macros, xstring, csname

I construct a marco named `\waterprint` to show waterprints in document by the package eso-pic.Please see the following codes for details.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,ifthen}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}
    %expample of the usage of \waterprint
    %\waterprint{pc}{0,0}{waterprint at page center}
    %#1 is the origin of coordinate,it should be:
    %- "pc" means page center
    %- "pll" means page lower left
    %- "pul" means page upper left
    %#2 is the location of waterprint
    %#3 is the content of waterprint
    \newcommand{\waterprint}[3]{%
        \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{0}[\locationofgridorigin]
        %   
        \let\positionpul\AtPageUpperLeft
        \let\positionpll\AtPageLowerLeft
        \let\positionpc\AtPageCenter
        %
        \edef\waterposition{position\locationofgridorigin}
        %
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
            %\csname position#1\endcsname{%This gives correct typeset
            \csname \waterposition\endcsname{%This gives wrong typeset
                \begingroup
                \normalsize
                \put(#2){#3}
                \endgroup
            }%\position
        }%\scopeofwaterprint
    }%\waterprint
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    some text
    \waterprint{pll}{30,30}{\parbox{10em}{This waterprint should be at lower left corner\\but now it's at page center}}
    \waterprint{pc}{0,0}{waterprint at page center} 
    %After calling \waterprint twice, both waterprints are typeset at page center, but what I expect is to put the typeset of \waterprint{pll} at page lower left corner.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that there are two `csname...\endcsname` in my code. The former gives correct typeset, but the latter gives wrong. Who can tell me the reason?

As the command `\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{0}[\locationofgridorigin]` must be kept for further reason, could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want that `\csname...\endcsname` is transformed into a single token before `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` is called.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,ifthen}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% example of the usage of \waterprint
% \waterprint{pc}{0,0}{waterprint at page center}
% #1 is the origin of coordinate,it should be:
% - "pc" means page center
% - "pll" means page lower left
% - "pul" means page upper left
% #2 is the location of waterprint
% #3 is the content of waterprint
\newcommand{\waterprint}[3]{%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{0}[\locationofgridorigin]%
  %   
  \let\positionpul\AtPageUpperLeft
  \let\positionpll\AtPageLowerLeft
  \let\positionpc\AtPageCenter
  \expandafter\AddToShipoutPictureBG\expandafter{%
    \csname position\locationofgridorigin\endcsname{%This gives wrong typeset
      \begingroup
      \normalsize
      \put(#2){#3}%
      \endgroup
    }%\position
  }%\scopeofwaterprint
}%\waterprint
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

some text

\waterprint{pll}{30,30}{\parbox{10em}{This waterprint should be at lower left corner\\
  but now it's at page center}}

\waterprint{pc}{0,0}{waterprint at page center} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, your code perfectly solve my problem. Many thanks. Yet I am still puzzled by the use of the second \expandafter--why puting the second\expandafter just before \csname is a wrong way, and how to understand the reason of puting the second \expandafter before the "{"? Thank you.

Comment: @lyl `\expandafter` acts on the second token following it. In this case, the first one jumps over `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` acting on the second `\expandafter`, which in turn jumps over `{` and acts on `\csname`. The expansion of `\csname` is the token built with its name consisting of the characters collected until the matching `\endcsname`.